# SQL - Using a select statement and loop to populate a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have to use a stored procedure to update some fields. The sp looks like this:

```
exec dbo.spMaintainConditionComponent
@Mask = 16
,@ConditionComponentUID = 
   ,@Status = 1
   ,@ArchiveUser = ''
   ,@ArchiveDate = ''
   ,@ArchiveReason = 'Removed'
   ,@ArchiveTypeID = '464'
```

All of the parameters have the same value except the @ConditionComponentUID which can be obtained from this select code:

```
SELECT     tbConditionComponent.ConditionComponentUID
FROM         tbAsset INNER JOIN
                  tbConditionComponent ON tbAsset.AssetUID = tbConditionComponent.ParentID
WHERE     (tbAsset.Status = 1)
```

I also need to use a 'while loop' or 'cursor' as multiple records can't be updated at the same time. Please could someone assist?

Comment: If you are selecting `@ConditionComponentUID` in stored procedure, why you have declared is as parameter to pass? rather than selecting it within the procedure

Comment: Why can you not update multiple records at the same time?

Comment: Using cursor or while loop will slow down the execution.

Comment: Its not my procedure so I can't manipulate it to include the select. Can't run multiple records as there is a separate audit trail table that won't allow me to. I'm not to worried about the time as long as it can be achieved, It's a one off exercise.

Comment: Create a table type and pass it to procedure. You can do the update in single procedure call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to update the data. The worst one is 'by using loop'. If you don't have any other choice **Use Cursor to LOOP through values:**

```
DECLARE LoopCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tbConditionComponent.ConditionComponentUID
        FROM tbAsset INNER JOIN tbConditionComponent ON tbAsset.AssetUID = tbConditionComponent.ParentID
        WHERE (tbAsset.Status = 1)

DECLARE @ConditionComponentUIDTemp AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

    OPEN LoopCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM LoopCursor INTO @ConditionComponentUIDTemp

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        exec dbo.spMaintainConditionComponent
        @Mask = 16
        ,@ConditionComponentUID = @ConditionComponentUIDTemp
        ,@Status = 1
        ,@ArchiveUser = ''
        ,@ArchiveDate = ''
        ,@ArchiveReason = 'Removed'
        ,@ArchiveTypeID = '464'

        FETCH NEXT FROM LoopCursor INTO @ConditionComponentUIDTemp
    END

CLOSE LoopCursor
DEALLOCATE LoopCursor
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error when running this: Msg 16922, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Cursor Fetch: Implicit conversion from data type uniqueidentifier to int is not allowed.

Comment: What is the data type of tbConditionComponent.ConditionComponentUID

Comment: Then change the variable ConditionComponentUIDTemp  type as uniqueidentifier. I updated the code

Comment: Thanks, giving it a whirl now